# Ask questions related to 'ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)'

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

When I was reading the mmdeploy source code,I keep seeing this line of code when loading a custom plugin:
`ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)`

It doesn't return anything, so why is it okay to call some of these functions or variables? Where does the DLL load into python?

I think the DLL is loaded into some python variables, but I, `print(locals)` and `print(globals)`, have not found any evidence of this, and all that is relevant online is the use of CDLL.

Comment: It's just being used to verify relevant dynamic libraries can be found and loaded.  `ctypes` otherwise isn't being used.  I found only two references to `ctypes` and neither save a reference to the loaded library to enable calling functions in the library

Comment: If that's what you said, it's just a test to see if it can load. So when I first started the python program and made sure it was callable, I removed `ctypes.CDLL`. The second time it was called it was wrong, so I don't think it was just a test to see if it was loadable.

Comment: Sounds like its a workaround to get the libraries to load then.  But `ctypes` isn't being used beyond getting the libraries to load.  If the libraries are Python extensions normally a `import` will do the library loading.  You'll have to ask the authors or dig in deeper than I did.  `CDLL()` does have the side-effect that the DLLs remain loaded but the functions in them are not being called by `ctypes` anywhere since the returned reference wasn't saved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I understand a little, I will ask the author.